# GNU Radio OOT block: AttributeError: module 'twoTypes' has no attribute 'passthrough_cc'

Tags: gnuradio

**What I'm trying to do:**
I am trying to write an OOT block for GNU radio that accept complex or byte values and just pass through. (My final target is obviously do some processing of the incoming stream, but it had so many errors, I had to go back to the basics)

**The error:**
I receive this error at runtime

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/maisun/Desktop/asdf.py", line 193, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/maisun/Desktop/asdf.py", line 171, in main
    tb = top_block_cls()
  File "/home/maisun/Desktop/asdf.py", line 82, in __init__
    self.twoTypes_passthrough_0 = twoTypes.passthrough_cc(0)
AttributeError: module 'twoTypes' has no attribute 'passthrough_cc'
```

**what I've tried:**
I have looked into the source of GR itself and tried to correct my yaml files, my header files. To the best of my knowledge, I have defined 'passthrough_cc' in the twoTypes.h header file as,

```
typedef passthrough<std::uint8_t> passthrough_bb;
typedef passthrough<gr_complex> passthrough_cc;
```

Obviosly i'm still doing something wrong here.

**my questions:**
I have 2 questions.

First, how can I correct the CPP code and the python module? so that I can call passthrough_cc without errors.

second, I am more comfortable in C language. So sometimes GR codes are very confusing to me. GR wiki has some nice guides available. But does anyone know if there is any guide/blog post that kind of discusses the workflow of GR? For example, when I trace my codes, I start from main() and follow the flow. with GR I always get lost.

**full code:**
https://github.com/maisunmonowar/gr-twoTypes

Comment: What I don't get in your code is that why have you created a template class? GNU Radio OOT modules can work without them.

Comment: @MobiZaman without the template class, I have to create 2 blocks for the same task. So I'd like to merge them into 1.

Comment: When you say that you receive that error at runtime, what exactly do you mean? Which command gives that error?

Comment: And did you try the answers of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35778455/gnu-radio-oot-module-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-mme-cpp?rq=1

Comment: I received a tip from the good folks of GNU radio IRC. It's basically missing pybind connectios. I'll try to answer and close this when I get the chance.